# Issue with exporting a variable with typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following typescript file:

```
let constants = {
    urls: {
      delegates: {
        AUTHENTICATION: {
          LOGIN: "auth/pub/login",                                                        // User Login (POST)
          LOGOUT: "auth/pub/logout",                                                       // User Logout
          PASSWORD_CHANGE: "security/pub/changepassword",                                           // Change user password (POST)
          PASSWORD_RESET: "security/pub/resetpassword",                                             // Reset user password (POST)
          PASSWORD_FORGOT: "security/pub/forgotpassword/{email}"                                    // Forgot password
        },
 ...

export constants.urls;//Does not compile...
```

I get the following error messages:

```
Expected function, variable, class, interface or namespace declaration.
Expression statement is not an assignment or call.
```

**edit**: I tried this:

```
const urls = constants.urls;
export urls;
```

and it results in the same error messages...

**edit 2**: Thanks to the reply below and comment by Matt, I came up with this which works fine:

```
const URLS = constants.urls;
export {URLS};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use

let constants = {
    urls: {
      delegates: {
        AUTHENTICATION: {
          LOGIN: "auth/pub/login",                                                        // User Login (POST)
          LOGOUT: "auth/pub/logout",                                                       // User Logout
          PASSWORD_CHANGE: "security/pub/changepassword",                                           // Change user password (POST)
          PASSWORD_RESET: "security/pub/resetpassword",                                             // Reset user password (POST)
          PASSWORD_FORGOT: "security/pub/forgotpassword/{email}"                                    // Forgot password
        },
 ...

const urls = constants.urls
export {urls};
```

Comment: For this to work, you need to do `export {urls}` then you can `import {urls} from 'xyz'`